# How can i limit rootscope to one controller ? I want to remove my rootscope.myValue in all the controller except one ! Any solution?

Tags: angularjs

I want to access this in only one controller if I move to another component I want to remove this value and make it null

`this.$rootScope.selectedPage = page;`

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: Instead of using rootscope pass the value from 1 component to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`$onDestroy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) inside your controller, and remove that value there

> $onDestroy() - Called on a controller when its containing scope is destroyed. Use this hook for releasing external resources, watches and event handlers

e.g.

```
$scope.$onDestroy = function() {
    this.$rootScope.selectedPage = null; // or delete it altogether
};
```

**EDIT:** 
However, if you just need that one variable in just one controller you should just bind it to `$scope` and avoid `$rootScope`, that way angularjs will free it by itself.

```
$scope.selectedPage = ...
```

General rule of thumb is to avoid `$rootScope` if you can.

Comment: but it's a brittle approach to call this method in all the controllers right ? can i find a smart soultion to overcome this ?

Comment: Is your controller limited to one view/route? If so you could listen to when the user changes route and set the value to null

Comment: usually if you need a variable just in one controller you would bind selectedPage  to the controller's scope `$scope.selectedPage`, than when you will change view the controller and $scope will bedestroyed and `selectedPage` will be removed.

Comment: @Lokeshch you can create a common component in which you can have onDestroy method. Since you have to do same operation in all component you can directly put that piece of code in common component onDestroy method. Later you can extend in method in other components.

Comment: Many thanks to all for the suggestions !! I solved my problem by checking a condition in oninit. The conditon is about checking the history url and if not matching the url i'm making the value to null